# On a result of Baer on the group $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

I was looking proof of a result of Baer for his result: the infinite abelian group $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ is not free abelian group. I was looking proof in Rotman's *Introduction to Homological Algebra* ($1979$):

(1) To prove non-free ness of above abelian group, it suffices to produce a non-free subgroup of it.

(2) Take $S$ to be collection of those members $(m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots,)$ in $G$ such that $p^k$ divides all except finitely entries of this infinite-tuple, for all $k\ge 1$.

(3) $|S|=2^{\aleph_0}$, so  $S$ is uncountable subgroup.

(4) It then follows that $\dim (S/pS)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is uncountable (**why?**)

(5) We finish proof by showing that $\dim(S/pS)$ is countable; (this gives contradiction, so $S$ is non-free.)

**Question:** It is simply step (4), I am not getting. It may be trivial, but I was unable to see the reason behind it.

Comment: $\dim(S/pS)$ countable implies $S/pS$ is countable, but $(3)$ is saying that $S$ is uncountable. How to compare these last two assertions?

Comment: (3) says that $S$ is uncountable. Now we assume that $S$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Since $S$ is uncountable, its basis as a ring over $Z$ must be uncountable. Therefore so is the basis of $S/pS$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

Comment: I guess another way of looking at this is by noting that the countable direct sum and countable direct product ($\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$) are different. The countable direct sum only allows finitely many nonzero entries and the countable direct product allows for arbitrary entries.

Comment: You're trying to obtain a contradiction from the assumption that $S$ is free. You haven't explicitly invoked that assumption in your argument. So it would seem likely that this freeness assumption would be needed at the non-obvious step (4). Once you realize that, I think you'd quickly come to the argument in @plop's comment.